# How can I prove these complex inequalities?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, exponential-function

How can I prove these complex inequalities?

> $|e^z-1|\leq e^{|z|}-1 \leq |z|e^{|z|}$, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

and

> $|e^z-1| \leq 2|z|$, for all $z \in B_1(0)$

Should I prove them wirh logarithm function?

Answer (score 1):

If $z\in\mathbb C$, then\begin{align}|e^z-1|&=\left|z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right|\\&\leqslant|z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+\frac{|z|^3}{3!}+\cdots\\&=e^{|z|}-1\end{align}and\begin{align}e^{|z|}-1&=|z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+\frac{|z|^3}{3!}+\cdots\\&=|z|\left(1+\frac{|z|}{2!}+\frac{|z|^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)\\&\leqslant|z|\left(1+|z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)\\&=|z|e^{|z|}.\end{align}Besides, if $|z|<1$, then\begin{align}|e^z-1|&=\left|z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right|\\&\leqslant|z|\left(1+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\cdots\right)\\&=|z|(e-1)\\&<2|z|.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This is really three questions. For the first one, write down the Taylor expansion of $e^z-1$ and then use the triangle inequality.

For the second one, you have a relation among nonnegative real numbers, which you might prove by Taylor expansion (show that $xe^x-e^x+1$ has nonnegative Taylor coefficients).

The third one follows immediately from the second and the simple fact $e \leq 3$.